# Is there a standard regular expression validator for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation

I have a Rails model with an attribute that is a regular expression. Is there a standard way to validate that the attribute's value is a valid regexp before saving?

**Update:** As per the accepted answer, here's what I did:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_each :bar do |model, attr, value|
    begin
      Regexp.compile value
    rescue RegexpError => e
      model.errors.add attr, "not a valid regular expression: #{e.message}"
    end
  end
  # [...]
end
```

Comment: U want to validate a regular expression..?? Or using a regular expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just ask `Regexp.compile` and catch errors.

Comment: Or `Regexp.try_convert` in Ruby 1.9.2, without needing to catch errors

Comment: @Beerlington: `Regexp.try_convert("re")         #=> nil` – I assumed Josh wanted to allow strings.